# Bug ao popular um Data GridView no Window Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Ao popular minha grid os valores não estão alinhados corretamente, conforme a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Este é o meu código no Load do Form:***

```
DatabaseRepository db = new DatabaseRepository();
var colunas = db.GetColumnsName();
var resultado = db.Get();

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

foreach (IDictionary<string, object> columns in colunas)
{
    var coluna = columns.Values.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
    dataTable.Columns.Add(coluna);

    foreach (IDictionary<string, object> rows in resultado)
    {
        foreach (var pair in rows)
        {
            if (pair.Key == coluna)
            {
                DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
                dataRow[coluna] = pair.Value;
                dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            }
        }
    }
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
```

***E esse meu código de acesso ao banco de dados:***

```
public class DatabaseRepository
{
    private Connection _Connection = new Connection();

    public DatabaseRepository()
    {

    }

    public List<dynamic> Get()
    {
        using(var Sql = _Connection.GetConnection())
        {
            Sql.Open();
            var resultado = Sql.Query<dynamic>("SELECT * FROM [seguranca].[tb_acao]").ToList();
            return resultado;
        }
    }

    public List<dynamic> GetColumnsName()
    {
        using(var Sql = _Connection.GetConnection())
        {
            Sql.Open();
            string query = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + "tb_acao" +"'";
            var resultado = Sql.Query<dynamic>(query).ToList();
            return resultado;
        }
    }

}
```

A ideia é pegar essas dados e colunas diretamente do banco, e na hora de listar concatenar as colunas com os valores para montar a grid.

Comment: Seu código tá extremamente confuso, tem coisa aí que nem faz sentido. Porque você não popula uma lista e joga no grid? O DataTable é realmente necessário?

Comment: @LINQ acho que o DataTable é o único jeito de popular a essa Grid, quanto por que não a lista, a ideia era pegar esses dados de forma dinâmica sem precisar criar uma model e tipar em uma listar

Comment: Sua ideia é fazer qualquer select no banco e conseguir jogar isso pra um mesmo DataGrid. Isso?

Comment: @LINQ isso mesmo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De forma geral, nada disso que está sendo feito é necessário.

É possível simplesmente atribuir uma lista como a fonte de dados do grid, desta forma cada item da lista será uma linha da tabela e cada propriedade de cada objeto representará uma coluna.

Note que esta abordagem de criar uma tabela genérica não é muito boa por si própria, eventualmente vai ser necessário fazer alguma adaptação em um caso específico e isso pode começar a ficar algo bem confuso.

```
var itens = new[]
{
    new { Id = 1, Nome = "Roberval", Idade = 35 },    
    new { Id = 2, Nome = "Joaquina", Idade = 29 },    
    new { Id = 3, Nome = "Marineide", Idade = 60 },    
    new { Id = 4, Nome = "Ericledes", Idade = 55 }
};

dataGridView1.DataSource = itens;
```

Este código produz o seguinte resultado:

[image: Tabela dinâmica com id, nome e idade]

---

Como você pretende jogar no *grid* os dados que vem do Dapper de forma dinâmica, vai precisar de alguma forma explicitar as colunas, neste caso não será possível usar uma lista como fonte de dados do *grid* porque o DataGridView procura por elementos concretos para montar a tabela.

[Neste post do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6298704/4190610) tem um método de extensão para enumeráveis dinâmicos que "transforma" a coleção num `DataTable`.

Perceba que agora a ideia parece pior ainda, seria muito mais fácil ter uma classe representando cada modelo, mesmo que não queira ter um grid para cada caso...

Seu código ficaria algo assim:

```
public class DatabaseRepository
{
    private Connection _Connection = new Connection();

    public DatabaseRepository() { }

    public IEnumerable<dynamic> Get()
    {
        using(var Sql = _Connection.GetConnection())
        {
            Sql.Open();
            return Sql.Query("SELECT * FROM [seguranca].[tb_acao]");
        }
    }
}
```

```
var db = new DatabaseRepository();
dataGridView1.DataSource = db.Get().ToDataTable();
```

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable(this IEnumerable<dynamic> items)
    {
        var data = items.ToArray();
        if (!data.Any()) return null;

        var dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (var key in ((IDictionary<string, object>)data[0]).Keys)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(key);
        }

        foreach (var d in data)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(((IDictionary<string, object>)d).Values.ToArray());
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: mas e se eu quisesse pegar essas propriedades dinâmicas do banco, onde cada "Select" tivesse campos diferentes?

Comment: @William Mas é exatamente o que tem na resposta, não? Você pode usar uma lista de qualquer tipo, incluindo um tipo anônimo (como na resposta).

Comment: é você tem razão, mas como eu colocaria os meu dados nessa lista dando um `for`? Porque a ideia é com os nomes das colunas e os dados fazer algo parecido com `reflection`. Porém não estou conseguindo listar direito porque o conexão me retorna um DapperRow

Comment: @William Eu não percebi de início o que você queria fazer como um todo. Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: vlw funcionou perfeitamente